# Value gets passed to function without me clicking the button

Tags: javascript

When I try to pass a value when a button is clicked the value gets passed anyway (even without me clicking the button). This is not supposed to happen because I want to hide an image only when the button is clicked
Why is this happening?

```
for ( i = 0; i < divs.length;i++){  
    knopdiv[i] = document.createElement('div');  
    divs[i].appendChild(knopdiv[i]);  
    knopdiv[i].innerHTML = '<button id="knop' +i+'">Afbeelding verbergen</button>';  
    knopdiv[i].onclick = hideMe(i, afb[i]);


function hideMe(nummer, afb){
console.log (nummer);
}
```

output without clicking:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Why isn't console just passing the number of the clicked button?

Comment: please post you full code and format it.

Comment: Why do you think the output should be padded?

Answer (score 0):

`knopdiv[i].onclick = hideMe(i, afb[i]);` when this statement is executed, `hideMe()` is fired!
change it to :

```
knopdiv[i].onclick = (function(i, element){
    return function(){
        hideMe(i, element);
    };
})(i, afb[i]);
```

Comment: +1 This _calls_ hideMe, instead of assigning it as a handler. It should be knopdiv[i].onclick = hideMe; to assign it as a handler

Comment: @wong2: check typo `fucntion`.

Comment: @ben When you do it like that notting gets passed? 
I am still learning so sorry if these are rookie questions

Comment: @Jarco That's true.If you just use `xx.onclick=hideMe;` nothing gets passed. you have to pass a function that call `hideMe(i, afb[i])` to `onclick`

Comment: @wong2. no, i gave you a +1 and someone gave you a -1. I'm finding the -1 highly unfair